# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp returns 404 on a PDF link

Tags: google-apps-script

The below code gives a 404. Tried the link with postman and browser works fine.

```
function testFetch(){
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get'
  };
  var url="https://psv4.userapi.com/c848028/u510634745/docs/d7/d16cec295970/India_Today_-_December_31_2018.pdf";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Comment: The link you are using returns 404 so does url fetch app

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed have you tried pasting it on your browser? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yep tried pasting it. It is a 404. Maybe it requires login to view

Comment: No. its a public link on a third party website. Could it have geographic access lock?

Comment: userapi.com redirects to vk.com, the Russian social networking site.  They have dedicated API methods to retrieve the docs associated with a particular user and all of them require user access key. The link is dead for me, so it's either private or expired.

Comment: Yes the link is now dead. They must be recycling it. No point keeping this question active. Thanks.